# ms access choose column for a report based on all values in that column

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

TableA has several columns that change over time.  Almost always, at least 4 or 5 columns have nothing but NA or NE.  I want to create a report that excludes those columns so any VBA must read all column values and exclude it if all values are NA or NE.
Sorry that I don't have any code but I'm not sure where to begin.  Should I open a recordset for each column and then use an if statement?

```
If Col1 = "NA" or Col1 = "NE"
    Exclude Col1
Else
    Include Col1
```

Comment: You still want the records, just don't want the values of "NA" and "NE" to display? Put an expression in textbox that returns Null if either of those two values in the field.

Comment: If the column contains only NA or NE, then I don't want the entire column - not even its name - just completely excluded.  Other columns may have NA in one row but numbers in other rows so they will be included.

Answer (score 0):

Not including the textbox means a design change. If you don't want even label to display, instead of label use a textbox to emulate a label. An expression in textbox can return Null or empty string if every record has NA or NE. Try:

`=IIf(Sum(IIf(fieldname <> "NA" And fieldname <> "NE",1,0))=0, "", "This Text")`

This expression assumes every record will have something in the field.